# AWS Access Key Rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, key-rotation

I am planning to rotate AWS keys.

My question is, will program throws an exception if we use expried AWS Keys?. If yes, what is the exception it is going to throw.
I didnt find any api to check the expired AWS Key.
Can someone pls help.

Answer (score 3):

IAM Users can have **two** active Access Keys.

Therefore, the normal rotation process is:

- Add a new Access Key
- Update all software to use the new Access Key (this can take several days)
- Revoke the old Access Key

Access Keys do not "expire". They are simply deleted. Trying to make a call on a deleted set of access keys will result in an error that the credentials are not found.

See: [How to Rotate Access Keys for IAM Users | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-rotate-access-keys-for-iam-users/)